# Sort "year/mon" column in R

Tags: r, sorting, date

I am trying to sort a data frame by column of "year.month" in R, but stuck at "as.Date" function. I have tried several other ways but no success. Can I get some help?
Here it is.
my code is

```
temp2_sort <- temp2[with(temp2, order(as.Date(year.month, format = "%y-%m"))),]
or 
temp2_sort <- temp2[with(temp2, order(as.Date(year.month, format = "%y-%b"))),]
```

but none of them works.

Thank you!

```
year.month  sale
2006/2  437
2006/3  52299
2006/9  175983
2006/12 57560
2007/2  10798
2007/3  12926
2006/5  61039
2006/8  135601
2006/6  54336
2006/10 72052
```

Comment: When your years are YYYY then the format spec must be "%Y"

Comment: I have tried %Y, %y, %YYYY, %yyyy, and others, all of them behaved same under this condition.

Comment: That column may be a factor and you need to use as.character().

Comment: Thank you for your careful thoughts; I did convert this column to character, but the sorting was still not right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `lubridate`:

```
 dat[order(ymd(dat$year.month)),]
```

Using `as.Date` you should add a dummy day part:

```
dat[order(as.Date(paste0(dat$year.month,'/1'),"%Y/%m/%d")),]
```